# What setting in Visual Studio is marking my saved file as dirty

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Many times when I just open a file in VS, it shows as changed in its TFS and if I do a compare with latest version, it shows nothing which is correct. 
What is it that it is changing upon opening and saving a file? ( both .XAML and .cs files) that marks them as dirty? So I can disable it

Comment: Are you sure that you're just opening the files? I often accidentally write a space or something like this in the open file and then it's marked as changed even after reverting the changes... Which is correct from a TFS point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save a file, the Last Modified timestamp gets... well... modified. This is when most source control systems start to think the file is 'dirty'.

Comment: yeah that's what I was thinking, is there some setting somewhere in TFS maybe that says ignore timestamp for diffing?

Comment: @DevWannaBe We are not using TFS (we use [Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com/home.html), but we also experience this 'Identical Files' issue, but we just ignore it...), but perhaps this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012144/visual-studio-tfs-shows-unchanged-files-in-the-list-of-pending-changes