# Committing files without changes

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

Sometimes I see a file without changes in the Visual Studio 'Pending Changes' view.
While we were using Visual Studio & TFS 2015 this was no problem. When I tried to commit I got a notification that there were no changes and the file disappeared in the 'Pending Changes' list.

Since we moved to 2017 these files will be committed. When I compare the last two versions of regarding file, there are no changes.
Is there a way to fix this behaviour, beside selecting 'Undo' by hand?

Comment: Which version control are you using - Git, SVN, TFS/VSTS or something else ?

Comment: We are using TFS 2017

Comment: Sorry I'm not using TFS2017 so I can't help here, but you could try using different versions of VS (2012/13/15/17 community editions perhaps) to see if they all behave the same - if they don't there is likely a setting in the VS options that facilitates either the TFS2015 or TFS2017 behaviour by default.

Comment: Which source control are you using, GIT or TFVC? Pending Changes  only with TFVC, however commit usually stands for GIT. In TFVC  called check in pending changes...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the unchanged files appear in the pending change list in your case. This is normal if a file becomes automatically checked out due to a change, and if ultimately the contents of the file are changed back to it's original state.

As a workaround to ignore the annoying phenomenon, you could use `tfpt uu . /noget /recursive $(SolutionDir)` command through **TFS Power Tools**.  More details please refer this similar question: [Visual Studio TFS shows unchanged files in the list of pending changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012144/visual-studio-tfs-shows-unchanged-files-in-the-list-of-pending-changes)

> **However, there are no Power Tools for Team Foundation Server 2017**
>
> ***Workaround:*** We are excited to let you know that most of the previous Power Tools have been integrated into TFS 2017. The Process
> Template Editor is one that has not been integrated, but we are going
> to publish a Process Template Editor tool for TFS 2017 to the Visual
> Studio Gallery shortly after TFS 2017 is available. We will provide
> the link here as soon as it’s published.
>
> *[Source Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-relnotes#a-idknownissues-aknown-issues)*

Otherwise, just check in these files or undo them manually.