# Visual Studio 2015 & TFS 2010 Pending Changes Issue

Tags: tfs, tfvc

My team is performing an analysis on which TFS version to upgrade to (from 2010).

One issue that we have faced daily is that TFS 2010 will log pending changes on files that are unchanged. For example, if I edit the JavaScript on `HomePage.aspx`, while leaving `HomePage.aspx.cs` and `HomePage.aspx.designer.cs` unchanged, the later two files will still log as pending changes, resulting with 3 files in the pending changes tab.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012144/visual-studio-tfs-shows-unchanged-files-in-the-list-of-pending-changes) post addresses this issue, and even has a semi-appropriate answer. **But I'm wondering, has this issue has been fixed in terms of using TFS 'out of the box' with TFS 2017 or 2018? Do I really need to use TFS Power Tools with the latest version of TFS to get around this annoyance?** I see many people saying that Power Tools doesn't solve the issue for all configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Visual Studio behavior, not TFVC. I would expect that the behavior will remain the same regardless of the version of TFS you use.

That said, you should upgrade to 2018, period. There's no benefit to upgrading to a version that's already supplanted by a newer major release.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for the input. Yeah I agree with you on the TFS upgrade version ... I guess I'm always hesitant with stability on new releases but you're probably right. So you think this is solely a VS thing huh? I will try VS 2017 and some of the recommended plugins on the linked post, perhaps that will resolve my issue. It seems to be a rather silly 'feature' at this point.

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel is correct. This behavior remains no matter which version of TFS you are using. You could see `HomePage.aspx.cs` and `HomePage.aspx.designer.cs` belong to `HomePage.aspx`, TFS treats them as one file. If you check the history of `HomePage.aspx.cs` and `HomePage.aspx.designer.cs`, you'll find no new history produces, as during check-in, TFS detects there is no changes for these two files:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the insight! I know that it won't produce history but I just find it annoying that it shows changes, when really ... there are no changes. It's especially frustrating when editing many files at once. Maybe I'm asking too much, ha!

Comment: Actually, you could submit a UserVoice at website below: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30925-team-foundation-server, product team will evaluate it carefully.