# Visual Studio 2015 has old version of TFPT which is unable to resolve workspaces

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

If I open the **Developer Command Prompt for VS2015** and run the command

```
cd /d [local path to branch mapping]
tf workfold
```

It shows the TFS mapping in my workspace correctly. But when I try using TFPT it keeps saying "Unable to determine the workspace"

Furthermore, **running tfpt with no arguments shows it is version 2013 even though I'm using 2015**. And installing Update 3 to VS2015 did not change anything!

How do I fix this? I've been having to migrate shelfsets across branches and [undo redundant changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544253) manually ever since my computer was upgraded by IT (read: replaced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following BFoust's answer to the question [How does TFPT.exe find what workspace to work in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758606) the solution for me was to open VS 2013 and connect it to the TFS server, since it had never been used before on my (new) computer.